# Serializing/Deserializing a subclass object in a method in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I want a save/load function in my class. I created a private subclass where I store every data that I want to save.

```
public class MyClass {

    private class Progress implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
        boolean val1 = true;
        int val2 = 0;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    private Progress progress = new Progress();    

    public void loadProgress() {
        progress = null;
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("./tmp/progress.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            progress = (Progress) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
            System.out.println("Progress class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

    public void saveProgress() {
        try
        {
            File f = new File("./tmp/progress.ser");
            f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(outputstream);
            out.writeObject(progress);
            out.close();
            outputstream.close();
        }catch(IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But when I want to try this code, it gives me java.io.NotSerializableException exception in the saveProgress() method, and because of this, the loadProgress() method is not working too. How can I serialize this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try serializing an instance of an inner class, the outer instance will also be serialized. In your case, `MyClass` is not serializable so it won't work. There are two possible workarounds:

- make `Progress` a static nested class
- make `MyClass` serializable

I would argue in favor of the first approach whenever it's possible since it serializes less data and therefore has better performance and space efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Outer class also needs to be `Serializable`, because each inner class has an implicit reference to the outer class.

So to solve this you need to mark `MyClass` as `Serializable` or make `Progress` a static class. Static classes don't have reference to the outer class.